# Magento : How to check if admin is logged in within a module controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, magento

I'm creating a Magento Module. Within the controller, I want to check if an admin is logged in or not. So the controller only will be accessible if there is a logged in admin.

I'm trying to use this code on my controller.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml')); 
$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');

// Use the 'admin/session' object to check loggedIn status
if ( $session->isLoggedIn() ) {
   echo "logged in";
} else {
   echo "not logged in";
}
```

but I always get "not logged in", even if I'm already logged in to the magento admin.

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?? any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I've got the same problem in a tiny_mce integration plugin

Comment: it works perfect for me http://magentocodes.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-to-check-admin-is-logged-in-or-not.html
with this we can check anywhere in magento.  thanks

Answer (score 19):

That is really strange. I use almost exactly the same code and it works all the time:

```
//get the admin session
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));

//verify if the user is logged in to the backend
if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()){
  //do stuff
}
else
{
  echo "go away bad boy";
}
```

Did you try var_dumping the $session variable? Maybe it will help you get on the right track...

Comment: yes, I did try var_dump the $session variable, there's something in that but seems there's no information about login status. What strange is, I tried this on another module, and it's work. Is there something to do with the module configuration file??

Comment: Interestingly enough I am having the same problem as as Calua - but only sometimes. I have two instances of magento setup on my server, one is the production version (at mydomain.com) and the other is a staging instance (at stage.mydomain.com).  The code snippets above work on stage but not production. Not sure why.  There might be some obscure setting somewhere, but the only thing that I KNOW is different is that my production has ssl and my stage doesn't.  Weird. I wonder if anybody has replicated the issue like this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your module's adminhtml controller is extending Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action. You can't check if an admin is logged in from a front end controller.

Answer (score 0):

`$user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');`

```
if($user->getUser()->getUserId()) {
   // admin logged
}
else {
   // not admin logged
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As David Tay said, you should extend your controller from `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`.

Anyway, the shortest way to check if admin is logged in is to call this helper method:

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getCurrentUserId();
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a new magento module, written by alan storm: https://github.com/astorm/Magento_CrossAreaSessions